# Reactjs Common state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to reactjs and I want an e-trade project. The problem is pressing the first "+" button, but increasing the number in the box next to it. How can I do this?
When I press the first, the other shouldn't increase because I will add more vegetable.
How can I solve this? Thank you so much

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      counter: 0
    };
  }

  increment() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      counter: this.state.counter + 1
    }));
  }

  decrement() {
    if (this.state.counter === 0) {
      this.setState({
        counter: 0
      });
    } else {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        counter: this.state.counter - 1
      }));
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style={{ marginTop: '50px' }}>
          <Card className="col-md-3" style={{  }}>
            <Card.Img variant="top" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/sivadass/image/upload/v1493620046/dummy-products/broccoli.jpg" style={{ width: '200px',marginLeft:'30px' }}/>  
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title style={{ textAlign: 'center'  }}>  Brocoli - 1 
              </Card.Title>
              <Card.Text  style={{ textAlign: 'center'  }}>
                1 $
              </Card.Text>
              <div style={{ textAlign: 'center'  }}>
              <Button onClick={this.decrement.bind(this)}>-</Button>
                <h2 value="1">{this.state.counter}</h2>
              <Button onClick={this.increment.bind(this)}>+</Button>
              </div>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
          <Card className="col-md-3" style={{ marginLeft:'10px' }}>
            <Card.Img variant="top" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/sivadass/image/upload/v1493620046/dummy-products/broccoli.jpg" style={{ width: '200px',marginLeft:'30px' }}/>  
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title style={{ textAlign: 'center'  }}>  Brocoli - 1 
              </Card.Title>
              <Card.Text  style={{ textAlign: 'center'  }}>
                1 $
              </Card.Text>
              <div style={{ textAlign: 'center'  }}>
              <Button onClick={this.decrement.bind(this)}>-</Button>
                <h2 value="1">{this.state.counter}</h2>
              <Button onClick={this.increment.bind(this)}>+</Button>
              </div>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
} 

export default App;
```

[image]

Comment: You need a separate counter state variable for each of them. If you have more than two cards then it is better to have an array of object for each of the card and a function which will take the index of the array which needs to be updated. Did you get what I am trying to say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check whether you are looking for the following type of solution or not? Please ignore the styling I have just implemented the functionality.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      items:[{
        name:"Veg 1",
        counter:0
      },{
        name:"Veg 2",
        counter:0
      }]
    };
  }

  increment = (index) =>{
    let localItems = [...this.state.items];
    localItems[index].counter += 1;
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      items:[...localItems]
    })
  }

  decrement = (index) =>{
    let localItems = [...this.state.items];
    localItems[index].counter -= 1;
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      items:[...localItems]
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      this.state.items.length ? this.state.items.map((item,index)=>{
        return (
          <div>
            <button onClick={()=>this.increment(index)}>+</button>
            <span>{item.name} - {item.counter}</span>
            <button onClick={()=>item.counter && this.decrement(index)}>-</button>
          </div>
        )
      }):null
    )

  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I wanted to do something like this.

Comment: Happy to hear that :) You are welcome @Emre. Enjoy coding with reactjs.